How to connect to OpenEdX server from linode?
I have a linode server that I ssh'ed into and set up OpenEdX with the following command:
pip install tutor[full]
tutor local launch

When I run those commands on my local machine, I can open a browser and go to: "local.edly.io"
But it's not working when I do that with my linode server. I'm addressing it via "linode_ip_address:local.edly.io"
I've tried reading the documentation and I couldn't find anything.

You need to have a domain name. You buy it and then connect it to your ip-address.
After that it will work
